# defining order of elements inside the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using Visual C# I am defining a set of Button and a set of RichTextBox inside my code (not visually) and here is the output.

[image]

I want to change the order of the elements such that a RichTextBox is always above any Button (unlike the picture that they are behind Button).

How can I do that programmatically ?

Comment: winforms or wpf? please show us the code: how exactly are you laying out the controls?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What was not clear for you in the above explanation?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you made any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **BringToFront**:

```
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox() { ... };
        // ...
        rtb.BringToFront();
```

or **SentToBack**:

```
        rtb.SendToBack();
```